# Manually adding method in a node module

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, node-modules, material-ui

I'm using `material-ui` for my website and the package found on `npm` is out of date with their most recent version (found on Github). I manually added in this line of code into their Theme Manager class, which reflects the changes:

```
setContentFontFamily(newContentFontFamily) {
  if (typeof newContentFontFamily !== "undefined" && newContentFontFamily !== null) {
    this.contentFontFamily = newContentFontFamily;
    this.component = Extend(this.component, this.template.getComponentThemes(this.palette, this.spacing));
  }
},
```

However, my application hasn't registered these changes and when I try to set a font:

```
ThemeManager.setContentFontFamily('Open Sans, Roboto, sans serif');
```

The console gives me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ThemeManager.setContentFontFamily is not a function
```

I'm using Browserify to bundle my client side 'require' dependencies. Is this a Browserify issue, an `npm` issue, or am I not understanding how node modules work?

Edit: Here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "FooProject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "highlight.js": "^8.7.0",
    "material-ui": "callemall/material-ui",
    "react": "^0.13.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.24.5",
    "react-highlight": "^0.5.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.1.7",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "author": "Tina Zheng",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babelify": "^6.1.3",
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "browserify": "^11.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-react": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-reactify": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast solution to your problem (aside from contacting the authors and asking them to update the npm) is to use the repository url as a dependency instead of the npm module:

```
git://github.com/user/project.git#commit-ish
```

If the repository is on GitHub you can use the short form:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "visionmedia/express",
    "mocha": "visionmedia/mocha#4727d357ea"
  }
```

([docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies))

If you just edit the dependencies directly, they will be overwritten every time there's a rebuild.

Comment: Are there any changes I need to make to my require statements? After uninstalling material-ui and reinstalling using the Github link, my build process couldn't find 'material-ui'

Comment: @TinaS.Zheng it shouldn't be necessary to change your code. Can you edit your question with your `package.json`?

Comment: edited! The line I changed was `"material-ui": "callemall/material-ui"`

Comment: @tinazheng It does look correct... have you run `npm update` after the change? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: I did indeed run `npm update` after the changes, but same errors thrown at me. I manually deleted the `material-ui` node package and installed it again via `npm`, and it worked this time. Thanks a bunch!